# Get value element same level?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="1" />
            <input id="button" type="button" value="Click me!" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get value of `input[type="text"]` by below code but It doesn't work, please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").bind("click", function() {
            alert($(this).siblings().find('input[type="hidden"]').val(););
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm no JQuery expert - but isn't the find checking for a hidden attribute that doesn't exist on the text input?

Comment: You have used input type text, but looking for input type hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first problem is that you're trying to find hidden inputs, rather than text based inputs. You also need to move your filter into the siblings call to make it work correctly, although you did have an extra semi-colon too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").bind("click", function() {
        alert($(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val());
    });
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/MzUy6/)

Answer (score 3):

`.find()` searches for children, so you cant to use it here. Just use `siblings()`

```
$(this).siblings('input').val()
```

Comment: +1 for being the only person to actually explain why the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find in siblings not in descendants of siblings.

```
  alert($(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
            alert($(this).prev('input[type="text"]').val());
        });
```

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/5ErLu/)

Comment: I believe that assumes however that the DOM will never change... so it isn't quite as robust as his original plan.

Answer (score 1):

use `jQuery prev()` as in `alert($(this).prev().val());`

It gets the immediately preceding sibling.

Comment: That assumes however that the DOM will never change... I'm not sure I'd see that as a safe assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").bind("click", function() {
            alert($(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Your input type is `text` not the `hidden`. You are fetching data using `hidden` in Jquery then use as below if this is hidden:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").bind("click", function() {            
        alert($(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val());
    });
});
```

if this is text:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").bind("click", function() {            
        alert($(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val());
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ngKs4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
alert($(this).siblings().find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
```

to

```
alert($(this).siblings().find('input[type="text"]').val());
```

Comment: I assumed that too and just tried in JSFiddle but get undefined changing it to that.

Comment: Find searches for children, the input is only a siblings() remove .find()